# find elements with jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a div:

```
<div id="div"></div>
```

with

```
$("#div").append("<div id='c'></div>")
$("#c").length
```

returns 0. what i can do for find the div width id = c after inserted in div #div?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4Q4cM/

Maybe `#div` element isn't appended to DOM tree itself? E.g., you're doing `$('<div id="div"></div>')` instead of inserting it in the document. **Nick Craver** also has a good guess.

Answer (score 1):

try doing:

```
$('div').append($('<div>').attr('id', 'c'))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have will work as long as you're running it in a `document.ready` handler, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#div").append("<div id='c'></div>")
  alert($("#c").length );  //alerts 1
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/CUuAk/), without the `.ready` wrapper, if it runs before `<div id="div"></div>` is loaded in the DOM, that `#div` selector won't find anything, and so it won't append anything to the `0` elements it found.

Answer (score -1):

First off, he div won't have a width until it contains some content. Try that.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the `length()` property (in this case the 'length' is basically the number of elements found by the selector), whereas you *seem* to be confusing it with `width`.

Comment: whoops. I did indeed miss that, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

```
$("#div #c")
```

will find what you're looking for

Comment: You should **very** rarely use a selector like this, an ID selector should *only* be `#id` in almost every case.  In this case it's not the issue.